# Function doesn't output data taken from user input

Tags: javascript, html, functional-programming

I'm writing a small program that takes user input from form text fields and when the generate button is clicked, it displays the collected data unto another div.

Problem is once it collects the input (I know this because I used an alert test to know where the function breaks), it doesn't display. It stops exactly where the display commands start.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Sure, definitely.

Comment: I'm asking from a mobile device and my battery's on 1%. I'll do so as soon as I can. But please, could you at least try diagnose the problem.

Comment: You call `generate()` but not `outputstuff()`.

Comment: Outputstuff() is a nested function. I made it so after it didn't work when it was just one function.

Comment: Do you really need `outputstuff()` to be in a function? Just execute those statements in `generate()`.

Comment: That was my first method. It didn't work too.

Comment: We can't see the whole `generate()` function in the screenshot. Do you have a call to `outputstuff()` anywhere in the `generate()` function? It should work if you do that.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - important clues, like how or even if you stop form submission from reloading the page, are missing. (Unrelated, consider using the `.textContent` property instead of `.innerHTML` to set the content of <SPAN> elements.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you needed to put the output functions into the nested function, they should have worked directly.

But with the nested function, you need to call it. Put:

```
outputstuff();
```

after `alert("working 8");`

Answer (score 0):

The generate button appears to submit the form on return from calling `generate` - the default type of a button is "submit" and it has the id "submitbutton".

If the page is reloaded from the server, the browser may fill in previously filled in input values but won't copy them into the SPAN elements.